# Silverlight DataGrid not showing data when more than 286 rows

Tags: silverlight

I am working with an application that is written for us by a third party company. In this application we want to have a sort of file system so we can download files that are on the machine where the silverlight application is running on. To list all the files, they have used a DataGrid. From this datagrid files can be downloaded to your machine. (Silverlight application can be access through the web).

Now I'm working with this application for a while and the number of files are growing (each day new files are generated) the datagrid is not showing any data. I tested and the limit is at 286 files, with 19 files on each page.
With 287 files, the DataGrid is not showing any data.

I'm familiar with programming languages, but Silverlight / C# is relatively new to me.

Edit: Of course I looked into the code but there is no limit on more then 286.

So my question, is there a limit for the DataGrid for the number of items / rows that it can handle?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is no (reasonable) limit on how many rows the DataGrid can show. I successfully loaded more than 1000 rows to the grid. Maybe the behavior is related to the way the paging is done? Is there a maximum amount of pages defined?

Comment: I can't find any limit in the maximum amount of pages defined. I also don't think that is te problem because 286 files with 19 files per page means 16 pages. But the 16th page has only 1 row, so 18 rows left empty. That's why I don't think there is a limit in the number of pages.